# Samsung a32 5g - Does having an app running in the foreground vs when you tab out of it when the screen is turned off take more battery/data?

Tags: battery, screen

In case you are confused on what I'm asking, let's say I open Pokemon go and have it running in the foreground, then turn my screen off. Will this take up more battery and data than if I tabbed out of the app, had it in the background, and then turned my screen off?

Comment: To my knowledge if the screen is turned off for Android this is like the app is going into background.

Comment: Sounds good, you mean while the app was still running right?

Comment: Yes. You can test this on your own. Use an app that records your GPS position and give the app the permission to access GPS only in foreground. To my experience GPS recording will stop if the app is in fore-ground and you switch off display.

Comment: I think that's true, when my screen is off the game does not follow location and lags behind until it catches up to me. Thanks! I do believe this will save data in that case correct?